# Configure Spring JPA with PostgreSQL for a large amount of db requests in time

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

our application is built on Spring Boot 2 (spring-data, JPA, Hibernate, Postgres, tomcat). Performance of an application is very bad because there is a lot of requests in time (for instance 2000 in 1 second). We are aware we need to rewrite it in future. But my question is if there is some solution which improves performance and executing a lot of requests without big changes in the code? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Do you use any kind of connection pool?

Comment: @BorLaze we didn't set it so I'm expecting it's default

Answer (score 1):

Its a broad question but some techniques that come in mind:

**1)** Optimistic locking. Thanks to that you do not need to physically lock tables / rows thus your concurring requests do not get queued and stack up. You still would get `OptimisticLockExceptions` and will need to  handle them but you get some performance benefits on the flip-side.

**2)** Try to avoid long methods wrapped in transactions that may lock certain data for more then needed. You may need to think about setting your `@Transactionl` methods with `PROPAGATION=REQUIRES_NEW` and making them shorter in general.

**3)** Try to test around with timeouts on your queries so that they do not hang for too long when blocked etc.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change code, I would suggest replacing hibernate with direct SQL with something like MyBatis. But if no code change, I only can suggest you to find bottle neck first.